# Does one of the battery failure damages the UPS DC capacitor bank?

Tags: capacitor, dc, ups, electrolytic-capacitor, batteries

Last day i found the DC capacitor bank of the 300kva UPS was burst/damaged.Upon further inspection one of the battery in the battery bank found damaged .My doubt is whether the failure of battery can result in the capacitor bank damage ??

Comment: Why not ???????

Comment: @Andyaka tell me the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electrolytic capacitors, especially aluminum types, have a limited life span. It may very well be that the capacitor failed to a short and placed a very heavy load on the battery preventing the internal charger in the UPS from being able to charge up the battery. As a result the battery fails.

It is also possible that UPS has a very crappy circuit design (many do). The battery could have reached a failed state at a very high internal resistance. A crappy internal charger may have increased its output voltage more and more trying to get the battery to take a charge. This would have placed a higher voltage on the capacitor bank than what the capacitor was rated for leading to a serious failure of the capacitor.

Comment: The battery which is failed is not the first one in the bank ...it is almost in the middle of a series bank .is it possible that this failed battery to cause some high resistance and there by result in more voltage across capacitor and damage it ?

Comment: I made two guesses in my answer after knowing much of nothing about your UPS. The point being made is that there could be multiple scenarios of what went wrong with the UPS and caused multiple components to fail. You can ponder all you want regarding "what if this" and "what if that" but at the end of the day you have to replace all the bad components to repair the faulty unit.

Comment: Just was eager to find the reason ...however your guesses made it more interesting .tq